# The deepest way in tree

Tags: ruby, tree

I have a tree with `n` elements that store something like `|id|parent_id|`. I need to find the maximum depth of this tree. I need to do this in Ruby, but pseudo code can help me too.

Comment: your question is unclear, but try depth first search and keep track of max depth you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `{id, parent_id}` pairs are in a dictionary/map, you can find max depth using [*memoization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique:

Main function (pseudocode):

```
Map tree; // <<=== This is your tree; id is the key; parent_id is the value
Map depth; // This map is used for memoization
int max = -1;
foreach pair in tree
    max = Max(memoized_depth(id, tree, depth), max)
```

Recursive depth function:

```
int memoized_depth(id, tree, depth)
    if (depth.containsKey(id)) return depth[id];
    if (!tree.contains(id)) return 0; // no parent means it's a root
    int res = memoized_depth(tree[id] // parent, tree, depth) + 1;
    depth[id] = res;
    return res;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following function (in pseudo code)

```
def level(id)
    find parent_id for id
    if parent_id then 
        level(parent_id) + 1 
    else 
        1    // no parent -> root
end def
```

and iterate over all items (i.e. ids) and search the maximum. In order to be more efficient you may store the already calculated depths within your tree structure or separately in a cache and access values from there.